# ksort doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, ksort

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($listings,1).'</pre>';

ksort($listings, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($listings,1).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [quick-brown-fox] => Array
        (
            [0] => Quick-brown-fox
            [1] => quick-brown-fox
            [4] => general_thumbs/quick-brown-fox.jpg
            [2] => 320
            [3] => 240
        )

)

Array
(
    [quick-brown-fox] => Array
        (
            [0] => Quick-brown-fox
            [1] => quick-brown-fox
            [4] => general_thumbs/quick-brown-fox.jpg
            [2] => 320
            [3] => 240
        )

)
```

I tried `foreach`, but it won't affect the original array, and `for` won't work because the its a key, not an index. What should I do in that case?

Comment: Well, `ksort()` does sort your array which has only one entry : `quick-brown-fox` => `Array(5)`. You need to do `ksort($listings[0])`.

Comment: I tried `foreach`, but it won't affect the original array, and `for` won't work because the its a key, not an index

Comment: `ksort($listings['quick-brown-fox'], SORT_NUMERIC);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks, but there maybe unknown number of arrays inside that one, not just one.

Comment: @3zzy ksort is not recursive. It will not dig down into your array and keep ksorting every sub-array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have nested array in this `$listings` array. To sort it, write it like this:

```
foreach($listings as $k => $a){
    ksort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);
    $listings[$k] = $a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_walk(
    $listings,
    function(&$value) {
        ksort($value, SORT_NUMERIC);
    }
);
```